# Why is mobile azure service extension not working in pcl?

Tags: facebook, azure-mobile-services

I referred azure mobile service through nuget package and I want to authenticate using azure mobile service.I created a mobile service in my azure portal and linked with facebook.Now when i tried to login using mobile service,then it asks for oauth token and mobile extension dll not getting where it only asks for provider.

Comment: Why everyone closing the question?I had gone through a lot of articles on mobile azure authentication.But am not using loginasync method with only provider name passed?Please answer

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Its not clear from above what the issue is you are facing and what you have tried.  Can you show how you are calling loginAsync for example and what is happening when you do so?

Answer (score 0):

In Mobile Services the PCL only supports:

```
LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider, JObject token);
```

Additional login options are provided but are platform specific and not available in the PCL only context.

Comment: So from where we will get token?